# SDK and AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I am trying to write code for an SDK. I need to make API calls.

I am using AFNetworking 2.0 to send a POST request to the server:

```
NSDictionary * params = [self formDictionaryFromCard: card];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString: [self apiUrl] parameters: params];

[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:@"Firefox" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];


AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
op.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

[op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {


    successBlock(responseObject);


} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {


    errorBlock(error);

}];

[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:op];
```

So far I have the above, but I can't figure out how to pass in headers (like the authorization header), or provide support for https.

Can anyone please help?

Also how can I know what http status code was returned?

Comment: You'll want to use `HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:success:failure:` and pass in a request that you have built with the headers.

Comment: Or set Authorization with the [request serializer](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/7570dfa3be638ec2fd8364c722628e8027504825/AFNetworking/AFURLRequestSerialization.h#L101)

Comment: @Jeremy You've asked at least three questions here. I suggest posting each as its own question and you'll be more likely to get answers.